# Почему событие scroll не работает на экранах меньше 800px?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Доброго времени суток!

Событие scroll не работает на экранах меньше 800px. Я смог решить эту проблему для мобилок используя событие touchmove. Но когда в Хроме включаешь режим разработчика, и просто сдвигаешь DevTools справа налево (не переходя в эмуляцию девайса, а просто сдвигая налево), то если окно html-документа меньше 800px, то событие scroll не срабатывает и событие touchmove тоже. Что мне делать?
Как мне быть в этой ситуации?

Я имею ввиду когда сжал окно меньше 800px, а потом скроллишь мышкой вверх-вниз. событие скрола не отлавливается.

Comment: У меня отлично отлавливается. Составьте [mcve] демонстрирующий вашу проблему

Comment: наверное, скрывается элемент, на который навешен обработчик